# I have a rigged object that I want to cut in half and be able to move around, but the armature deforms it

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging

I made this elephant and rigged it, and now I want to cut it in half and be able to drag the two halves away from each other. However, whenever I do this, the armature distorts and deforms the object, and it looks horrible. Is there a way to apply the armature or something so that when I bisect the object and move each half the two objects don't become distorted? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is animate your rig until you get to the point where you need it to split in two. When you get to that point, go into Object Mode, select the rig, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + select the character mesh that is bound to it, and then duplicate them both (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>). You will have a copy of both armature and character mesh, which means all vertex weights will be inherited, as well as all keyframes, up to that point. Put an invisible material on the half of the new character mesh that you don't want to be rendered, and also put one on the opposite half of the old character mesh. When you add new keyframes to the new rig, it can look as if the character is splitting in two.

Comment: Ok that works for an animation but I didn't need to animate my object, only change its position easier, so I realised rigging was the wrong way to come about this. I just remodeled my mesh and bisected and separated it, so that I could apply modifiers to each half. Thanks for your answer though!